How to adjust keyframe on path without effecting other points
How do I only change the values at a single keyframe using 'G' without effecting the other points on the motion path?
I have 3 keyframes for a ball moving in a parabola motion, but when I try to adjust keyframe #2 (the peak of the parabola) by moving the MAIN bone upward by using 'G' and locking it in the z direction to just drag it up a bit, it also moves the start and end keyframes 1 and 3. But if I manually adjust the z value from 10 to 20, it seems to correctly move only the keyframe #2 value without effect the start and end keyframes. Thanks for any help on this.
